# How to Add Button to Custom View Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, button, dynamically-generated

I'm a starter in Android Programming, and I'm developing a program by modifying some classes I found [here.](http://www.anddev.org/a_bouncing_ball_-_basic_graphics_animation_demo-t283.html) So far I have the `DrawView` class as follows:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
   private Ball ball1;

   private Button kapabut;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        ball1 = new Ball(context,R.drawable.ortatop);       

       kapabut=new Button(context);  //here, I cannot seem to add a button.
       kapabut.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
       kapabut.setText("xXx");
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // move the balls at every canvas draw
        ball1.moveBall();

        //draw the balls on the canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball1.getBitmap(), ball1.x, ball1.y, null);
        // refresh the canvas
        invalidate();
    }    
}
```

The ball is created and moves, but I cannot seem to get the button "kapabut" anywhere. How can I make this button appear, and add an `onClick` method too?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

P.S.: I tried and added a Button using an XML layout, but now I want to make it with this class, and setting `setContentView(new DrawView(this));` in Main.java

Answer (score 0):

You can not add other `View` objects in View's `onDraw()` method, their is no any `addView()` method in View class.

To get it work extend your **DrawView** class with [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) now you can add other View in this. As `addView()` method belongs to `ViewGroup` Class.

Something like,

```
public class DrawView extends ViewGroup {
```

Comment: But I still can't add the button. I tried linearlayout.addView(button) with button parameters and text set. What could be the problem now?

Comment: Actually, the same thing which I mentioned about extending `ViewGroup` you can use other Layout also for implement your functionality, i.e. extends `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` also helps you. Now in this after adding views which you want.